# XSLT 3.0 json-to-xml() not working with valid json

Tags: json, xml, xslt

Below json is a valid Json. But XSLT 3.0 transformation json-to-xml() not working and showing some error in json syntax.

```
{
    "identifier": {
        "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
    }
}
```

What can I do to make it work. I think some thing related to escaping characters need to be done here. Any pointer on this would be great help.

Try execution of code at this location [Fiddler](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTz9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to put your JSON with XML into an XML input document, that is causing the problem with the XML parser trying to parse that input you have put into the fiddle, if you use a string parameter for the stylesheet, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJf, you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="json-input" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[{
            "identifier": {
                "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
                }
        }]]></xsl:param>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml($json-input)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output is

```
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map key="identifier">
      <string key="use">&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</string>
   </map>
</map>
```

You could also use the same CDATA escaping in the primary XML input, that is, use

```
<root><![CDATA[{
            "identifier": {
                "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
                }
        }]]></root>
```

as the XML input and then

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(root)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

as the XSLT, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJf/1, and you get the same result as above.

Answer (score 3):

In the "fiddler" you point to, you have an XML file:

```
<data>{
            "identifier": {
                "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
                }
        }
</data>
```

The problem is that this is invalid XML. The XML parser sees a start tag `<data>`, followed by a text node, followed by a start tag `<div xmlns=\`, and complains because the first character after `xmlns=` must be `"` rather than `\`.

So you have XML nested within JSON nested within XML. When you nest XML within JSON you must escape `"` as `\"`, which you have done; but when you nest JSON within XML, you must escape `<` as `&lt;`, which you have not done. The simplest solution is probably to use a CDATA section:

```
<data><![CDATA[{
            "identifier": {
                "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
                }
        }
]]></data>
```